# Order items alphabetically in Django admin site's multi-select box

Tags: django, django-admin, frontend, multi-select, django-1.8

My team's having a lot of trouble finding items in Django admin site's multi-select drop-downs. How do I order items in multi-select drop-downs alphabetically?

Answer (score 2):

Try doing that with the form that you are entering on Form Admin

```
from django import forms

class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
        attribute = forms.MultipleChoiceField(queryset=Model.objects.order_by('name'))

        class Meta:
            model = YourModel
```

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "the form you are using the admin."